# position of the points in scatter plot d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I just started to learn d3.js last week and I am trying to create a scatter plot. I am expecting the t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 on the y axis. And x-anxis is from 1 to maximum value of quality. But after running the code below, it looks like the position of the points are not correct. Two of them even out of the range of y aixs. I am not able to figure out why. Can anyone help to fix the code and explain why? Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dot Plot</title>
    <style> 
     .axis path,
     .axis line{
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crishpEdges;
        }    
    .circles { opacity: .7; }
    </style>
  </head>
   <body>
    <h1 style = "text-align:center;">Dot Plot Example</h1>     
   </body>

  <body>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var data = [
     {"custid": 1, "Type": "t1","quality": 7},
     {"custid": 2, "Type": "t2", "quality": 2},
     {"custid": 3, "Type": "t3", "quality": 3},
     {"custid": 4, "Type": "t4", "quality": 7},
     {"custid": 5, "Type": "t5", "quality": 2}   
    ];

        data.forEach(function(d){
        d.quality = +d.quality;
        d.Type = d.Type;
        return console.log(data);
    })

    var margin = {t:30, r:20, b:40, l:40 },
        w = 600 - margin.l - margin.r,
        h = 500 - margin.t - margin.b;

    var color = d3.scale.category20c();

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, w])
        .domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d){return d.quality})]);

    var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
         .range([h,0])
         .domain(data.map(function(d){return d.Type;}));    

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(8);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(6);

    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w + margin.l + margin.r)
        .attr("height", h + margin.t + margin.b)
        .style("margin-left", "auto")
        .style("margin-right", "auto")
        .style("display", "block")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.l + "," + margin.t + ")");     

    svg.selectAll("circle")
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("class", "circles")
       .attr({
        cx: function(d) { return x(d.quality); },
        cy: function(d) { return y(d.Type); },
        r: 8
      })
       .style("fill", function(d){return color(d.Type);});

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.l + "," + (h - 20 + margin.t) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.l + "," + margin.t + ")")
        .call(yAxis);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are the positions not correct? What do you expect instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems. First, the ordinal scale as you use it expects a 1:1 mapping between domain and range elements. That is, for each element in the array given to `.range()`, there needs to be a corresponding element in the array given to `.domain()`. In your case, you have 5 domain values, but only 2 range values. In cases like this, you should use [`.rangeRoundPoints()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_rangeRoundPoints), which will subdivide the interval automatically depending on the number of values in the domain:

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .rangeRoundPoints([h,0])
     .domain(data.map(function(d){return d.Type;}));
```

Second, you're translating the containers for the axes by the margin, but don't include that for the points. You simply need

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vny7p798/).

Comment: Thanks so much! How do I move the tick of t1 a little bit upper on y axis, since it locates on x axis.